# WiFi suddenly not working

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I brought my Dell Latitude E6410 running Ubuntu 15.04 to a place where there was public WiFi. I'm using i3-gaps WM,so I attempted to connect via the terminal. However when I ran
`sudo dhclient wlan0`
 I got the error 
`/sbin/dhclient-script: 7: [: =: unexpected operator`

Now that I am back at my house, I cannot connect tomy WiFi network, even through GUI. I am able to connect via Ethernet however. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The question is old, but i came across the same error today. 
I found out that the problem is produced by the **ddclient** startup script.
To get rid of the error you need to modify the line 7. from /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ddclient and add quotation marks around the variable.

Present state:
[ $run_dhclient = "true" ] || exit 0

Should be:
[ "$run_dhclient" = "true" ] || exit 0

Comment: Just to note that this bug has been reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ddclient/+bug/1704159.